# Cannot copy object of class derived from matlab.mixin.Copyable

Tags: matlab, class, oop

I want to create a copy of an object of a class derived from  `matlab.mixin.Copyable`.

```
classdef ImageReaderAny < ImageReaderBase &  matlab.mixin.Copyable
```

If I create the object using

```
reader = ImageReaderAny(processFolder);
```

and try to create a copy using

```
reader2 = copy(reader);
```

The original object is changed when I access the copy.

I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please extend your example so that it is a [mcve] we can use to reproduce the issue

Comment: [inherit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/hierarchies-of-classes-concepts.html) then [overload](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/overloading-functions-for-your-class.html)?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? The copy is shallow. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.copyable-class.html#mw_9450e0ed-d4fc-4eb4-baa9-1af479c42060 — But you’re probably better off value classes rather than handle classes. Their use is more in line with MATLAB syntax. Use a handle class only if the class is an interface to external resources (a file, a GUI element, a network commection, etc.) If it just stores data, use a plain value class.